# How do I go to the last Google Search result?

Tags: google-search

When I search on Google, the statistical estimate is wrong (e.g., [33600](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22scala%20di%20lunghezza%20d%27onda%22&sca_esv=588287231&sxsrf=AM9HkKm6HM_PSh6C0qnrBpwtCGg85oF7GQ%3A1701851686846&ei=JjJwZaqWM9iD9u8Pm7iG-Ak&ved=0ahUKEwiqwYTKs_qCAxXYgf0HHRucAZ8Q4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=%22scala%20di%20lunghezza%20d%27onda%22&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiGyJzY2FsYSBkaSBsdW5naGV6emEgZCdvbmRhIjIIECEYoAEYwwRIniNQvQZYoSJwAXgBkAEAmAF2oAGHBaoBAzUuMrgBA8gBAPgBAcICChAAGEcY1gQYsAPCAgYQABgeGA3CAgsQABiABBiKBRiGA8ICChAhGKABGMMEGAriAwQYACBBiAYBkAYD&sclient=gws-wiz-serp#ip=1) results for the sentence "scala di lunghezza d'onda", instead the actual number is 23; [1190](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22scala%20delle%20lunghezze%20d%27onda%22&sca_esv=588287231&sxsrf=AM9HkKl38w7FdY1ixCr51TLiHciNnMNTxA%3A1701851680534&source=hp&ei=IDJwZYCBHpS_xc8Po_KOwAc&iflsig=AO6bgOgAAAAAZXBAMBNf4niMN-lSSn1isQLAQ_1hI7zP&ved=0ahUKEwiAkYHHs_qCAxWUX_EDHSO5A3gQ4dUDCAo&uact=5&oq=%22scala%20delle%20lunghezze%20d%27onda%22&gs_lp=Egdnd3Mtd2l6Ih4ic2NhbGEgZGVsbGUgbHVuZ2hlenplIGQnb25kYSIyBRAhGKABMgUQIRigATIFECEYoAFI9ylQAFjEKHAAeACQAQCYAdwCoAGmF6oBCDI1LjQuMC4xuAEDyAEA-AEBwgIKECMYgAQYigUYJ8ICCxAAGIAEGIoFGJECwgILEC4YgAQYxwEY0QPCAgUQLhiABMICBRAAGIAEwgIEEC4YJ8ICChAAGIAEGBQYhwLCAgQQIxgnwgIQEC4YgAQYFBiHAhjHARivAcICCxAuGIAEGMcBGK8BwgIOEC4YgAQYywEYxwEYrwHCAggQLhiABBjLAcICCBAAGIAEGMsBwgIREC4YgAQYywEYxwEYrwEYmAXCAgYQABgWGB7CAgkQABgWGB4Y8QTCAgsQABgWGB4Y8QQYCsICCxAAGIAEGIoFGIYDwgIHECEYoAEYCsICCBAhGBYYHhgd&sclient=gws-wiz#ip=1) results for the sentence "scala delle lunghezze d'onda", actual number of results: more than 60).

I use the extension SEOquake to see the number of the result on the left side (1. result one, 2. result two, etc.).
Is there a way to go to the last result on Google?
If yes, in that case, the above extension can tell me the number corresponding to the last result.

My question is not a duplicate of the question [Why on the first page Google says there are thousands of results but on the last page there are less than a hundred?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/14972/why-on-the-first-page-google-says-there-are-thousands-of-results-but-on-the-last) because I know that number is an estimate, I'm asking how to scroll until the last result.
Before Google introduced the scroll modality, I was able to do it by jumping from page 1 to page 10, etc.; it didn't take much time—less than 1 minute.
Instead, now it's like you go from page 1 to 6 and then from to 7, 7 to page 8...

Comment: What does Google look like for you? For me (this time at least), it's an infinite scroll. Also, note that the number of results reported by Google at the start of a search has [never been accurate](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/397/191178).

Comment: @Blindspots Can you please reopen? I have the answer to this question (how to get to the last result that Google will show you) and it wouldn't make sense to post it on the duplicate since it doesn't answer that question.

Comment: Hi. I'm a Web Applications Stack Exchange **Community Moderator** (volunteer) and a Webmasters Stack Exchange **user** with experience on the topics related to this site. I migrated the question from Web Applications to Webmasters because the underlying problem concerns SEO rather than using Google (websearch) as an end-user. SEO is a topic that "belongs" to Webmasters, not to Web Applications. Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

Immediately after you search, add `&start=300` (or another somewhat large multiple of ten) to the URL. (For a fresh search, before you click on "More results", it shouldn't already been in the URL, but replace it if it is.) If you chose a sufficiently large number, you should see a page with no results, but at the bottom (after it loads) it will tell you how many results the search should return:

[image: Your search - xyz - did not match any documents... In order to show you the most relevant results, we have omitted some entries very similar to the ### already displayed.]

According to my testing, that number in "the ### already displayed" seems to be a very close approximation, not always the real number of results. Change `&start=300` in the URL again according to that number, fiddling around as needed. In my case, `start=230` had results but `start=240` did not. (Unfortunately, this technique breaks the pagination and probably interferes with some extensions, so you can only navigate by changing the URL when using this technique. Also, clicking on "repeat the search with the omitted results" will take you back to the start of the search but prevent you from seeing the close estimate of results again with this technique, and for my search that option only showed results up to page 210—less than the original search.)

Note: For some searches (such as the first one in your post), it was faster to hold down the space bar and click on "More results" (if it even appears) instead of messing with the URL. (This seems to load results 10 at a time.)

Comment: I tried it by searching "scala delle lunghezze d'onda", and it has some problem: `https://www.google.com/search?q=%22scala+delle+lunghezze+d%27onda%22&sca_esv=589119146&sxsrf=AM9HkKn9sNHwGHVHm5J5o78zqpOey4iunA%3A1702056986400&ei=GlRzZeP0F-GMxc8PiYiQ4Ac&ved=0ahUKEwjj6b6wsICDAxVhRvEDHQkEBHwQ4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=%22scala+delle+lunghezze+d%27onda%22&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiHiJzY2FsYSBkZWxsZSBsdW5naGV6emUgZCdvbmRhIjIHECMYrgIYJ0h6UABYAHAAeACQAQCYAWugAWuqAQMwLjG4AQPIAQD4AQL4AQHiAwQYACBBiAYB&sclient=gws-wiz-serp#ip=1&start=1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

Comment: @FedericaGuidotti Try making the number large, but not overly large. I think that searches always return 500 results or less.

Answer (score 1):

The only legitimate reason to skip to the last search results in a business/professional setting is for [search engine optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization) purposes. Before Google changed the search results page design/layout from paged to infinity scroll, it might be "easy" to jump to the last page by using the corresponding paging URL parameter. Still, nowadays, that doesn't work anymore. However, that was a *hack*, a good one, but it was still a *hack*.

If you are interested in learning how the results appear on the Google search results page, schedule to spend some time on [Google Search Central](https://developers.google.com/search), the website from Google that explains how Google (search engine) works.

There is a lot of content created by independent parties that might be extremely helpful. Be careful when choosing. Look for reliable and **updated** sources.

On the other hand, you might need to learn about the modern technologies used to create web applications, how web browsers work, and what options users might have to customize web applications by taking advantage of the client-server architecture used by most web applications. More specifically, you might need to spend some time learning the basics of HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and [Document Object Model (DOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model).

## Regarding *Hacks*

The term *hack* was used long ago by a community of problem-solving-minded people to refer to non-elegant, unusual but practical and working solutions. Some others might use *quick and dirty* to refer to similar solutions. Later, the term *hack* became part of pop culture primarily due to people exploting computer vulnerabilities; unfortunately, the most notorious cases were those done with deceiving / malicious purposes.

When collaborating with other users, i.e., when sharing trial and error efforts, please remember that localization, personalization, and other factors might affect each other's experiences.

## Resources

- [Understand & manage your location when you search on Google](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/179386?hl=en),
- [Personalization & Google Search results](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/12410098?hl=en)